# mysql trigger is not working on wamp server

Tags: mysql, database, triggers

I have three tables namely:

1. tab_m_blood
2. tab_m_donar
3. tab_t_bloodstock

"tab_m_blood" entries are below:

```
  bgId      |   bGroup
  --------------------
  1         |   A+
  2         |   A-
  3         |   B+
  4         |   B-
  5         |   AB+
  6         |   AB-
  7         |   O+
  8         |   O-
```

tab_m_donar entries are below:

```
dId  | donarName  | donarAddress | donarContact | donarDisease | bgId | bloodUnit
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1    | a          | xy           | 111          | NA           | 2    | 20
2    | b          | uv           | 222          | NA           | 2    | 30
```

tab_t_bloodstock entries are below:

```
  bgId | bUnit
  ------------
  1    | 0
  2    | 0
  3    | 0
  4    | 0
  5    | 0
  6    | 0
  7    | 0
  8    | 0
```

1. What i want is that when a donar donate their blood in "tab_m_donar",the blood stock for respective blood group will update in "tab_t_bloodstock"
2. I want to write a trigger on "tab_m_donar" which will act like when any data will insert on "tab_m_donar" ,the data will update "tab_t_bloodstock".
3. "bgId" in the "tab_t_bloodstock" is the FK of the PK-->"bgId" in the "tab_m_blood".

I already wrote the trigger below but it is not working:

```
CREATE TRIGGER updatestock AFTER UPDATE ON tab_m_doner
FOR EACH ROW 
begin
if old.bgId is not null then
update tab_t_bloodstock
set bUnit=bUnit-old.bloodUnit
where bgId=old.bgId;
end if;
if new.bgId is not null then
update tab_t_bloodstock
set bUnit=bUnit+new.bloodUnit
where bgId=new.bgId;
end if;
end
```

Please help me out.

Comment: You need another trigger `AFTER INSERT` to add to blood stock when a new donor comes in.

Comment: This thing might be begging for a transaction wrapper, as you are updating On Hand amts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can implement this on SQL Server but I actually don't know how to do it on MySQL

I guess there is a transformation you can implement manually

```
CREATE TRIGGER updatestock 
 ON dbo.tab_m_donar
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS

-- insert
Update tab_t_bloodstock
set bUnit = bUnit + i.bloodUnit
from tab_t_bloodstock s
inner join (
    select i.bgId, i.bloodUnit
    from Inserted i
    left join Deleted d on i.dId = d.dId 
    where d.dId is null
) i on i.bgId = s.bgId


-- update
Update tab_t_bloodstock
set bUnit = bUnit + u.ins - u.dels
from tab_t_bloodstock s
inner join (
    select i.bgId, i.bloodUnit ins, d.bloodUnit dels
    from Inserted i
    inner join Deleted d on i.dId = d.dId 
) u on u.bgId = s.bgId



-- delete
Update tab_t_bloodstock
set bUnit = bUnit - d.bloodUnit
from tab_t_bloodstock s
inner join (
    select d.bgId, d.bloodUnit
    from deleted d
    left join inserted i on i.dId = d.dId 
    where i.dId is null
) d on d.bgId = s.bgId

go
```